# How to record data of one excel sheet and store another sheet after an interval

Tags: excel, vba

I get a VBA code for this but I am not able to capture the data in row wise. It stores column wise data only.

> ```
> Set Capture = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5")
> ```

This code capture the data First A1 to A5 column then B1 to B5 column in the same row and so on. But I am trying to capture like First A1 to C1 in one row then A2 to C2 in next row and so on. Is there any way I can dot it?
[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hOYc.jpg)

```
Dim NextTime As Double



Sub RecordData()
Dim Interval As Double
Dim cel As Range, Capture As Range
Interval = 5    'Number of seconds between each recording of data
Set Capture = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5") '****Problem in this code.Only****
With Worksheets("Sheet2")   'Record the data on this worksheet
Set cel = .Range("A5")  'First timestamp goes here
Set cel = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cel.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
cel.Value = Now
For i = 1 To 5
cel.Offset(0, 1 + (i - 1) * Capture.Rows.Count).Resize(1, Capture.Rows.Count).Value = 
Application.Transpose(Capture.Columns(i).Value)
Next i

End With

NextTime = Now + Interval / 86400
Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the idea to loop through rows? I am somehow missing the point. Can you make a screenshot, explaining why `Set Capture = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5")` is a problem?

Comment: Also - `cel.Offset(0, 1 + (i - 1) * Capture.Rows.Count).Resize(1, Capture.Rows.Count).Value = 
Application.Transpose(Capture.Columns(i).Value)` can probably be simplified, but adding a screenshot will help.

Comment: ok I will add the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code could be rewritten as:

```
Dim NextTime As Double 
Sub RecordData()
Dim Interval As Double
Dim cel As Range, Capture As Range
Interval = 5    'Number of seconds between each recording of data
Set Capture = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:N2") 'Capture this column of data
With Worksheets("Sheet2")   'Record the data on this worksheet
Set cel = .Range("A5")  'First timestamp goes here
Set cel = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cel.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
cel.Value = Now
cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, Capture.Cells.Count).Value = Capture.Value


End With

NextTime = Now + Interval / 86400
Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData"
End Sub
```